# XML vs XSD verification

Tags: xml, xsd

I have a several XSD and try to verify my XML against them as:

First one (with nm_service values in (vl_1, vl_2)) **common.xsd**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    targetNamespace="http://tii.ru/crmcom/uiconf/common"/>

    <xsd:simpleType name="nm_service">
        <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
            <xsd:enumeration value="vl_1" />
            <xsd:enumeration value="vl_2" />
        </xsd:restriction>
    </xsd:simpleType>
</xsd:schema>
```

Second one (with some recursion) **recur.xsd**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<!--XML Schema generated by QTAssistant/XML Schema Refactoring (XSR) Module 
    (http://www.paschidev.com) -->
<xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd"
    elementFormDefault="qualified" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:p="http://tii.ru/crmcom/uiconf/common">
    <xsd:import namespace="http://tii.ru/crmcom/uiconf/common"
        schemaLocation="common.xsd" />
    <xsd:element name="object">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element ref="recursive" minOccurs="0" />
                <xsd:element ref="center" minOccurs="0" />
            </xsd:sequence>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
    <xsd:element name="recursive">
        <xsd:complexType>
            <xsd:sequence>
                <xsd:element ref="recursive" minOccurs="0" />
                <xsd:element ref="center" minOccurs="0" />
            </xsd:sequence>
            <xsd:attribute name="nm_service" type="p:nm_service"></xsd:attribute>
        </xsd:complexType>
    </xsd:element>
    <xsd:element name="center" />
</xsd:schema>
```

Element with the name of **recursive** can have attribute nm_service with values defined in common.xsd

But when I try to validate

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<!-- Sample XML generated by QTAssistant (http://www.paschidev.com) -->
<object xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd">
    <recursive>
        <recursive nm_service="val_1" >
            <recursive>
                <center>
                    <recursive>
                    </recursive>
                </center>
            </recursive>
        </recursive>
    </recursive>
</object>
```

I got error The qname values does not resolve to a(n) simple type definition at

```
<xsd:attribute name="nm_service" type="p:nm_service"></xsd:attribute>
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Note**: It seems that you may have posted XSDs inconsistent with the error message you reported.

Two main errors to fix:

1. In common.xsd, `xsd:schema` is self-closed where it shouldn't be.
2. In try.xml, `val_1` should be `vl_1`.

Altogether, the following XSDs will validate your XML successfully:

### common.xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsd:schema xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
            targetNamespace="http://tii.ru/crmcom/uiconf/common">

  <xsd:simpleType name="nm_service">
    <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string">
      <xsd:enumeration value="vl_1" />
      <xsd:enumeration value="vl_2" />
    </xsd:restriction>
  </xsd:simpleType>
</xsd:schema>
```

### recur.xsd

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd"
            elementFormDefault="qualified" 
            xmlns="http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd"
            xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
            xmlns:p="http://tii.ru/crmcom/uiconf/common">
  <xsd:import namespace="http://tii.ru/crmcom/uiconf/common"
              schemaLocation="common.xsd" />
  <xsd:element name="object">
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element ref="recursive" minOccurs="0" />
        <xsd:element ref="center" minOccurs="0" />
      </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>
  <xsd:element name="recursive">
    <xsd:complexType>
      <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element ref="recursive" minOccurs="0" />
        <xsd:element ref="center" minOccurs="0" />
      </xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:attribute name="nm_service" type="p:nm_service"></xsd:attribute>
    </xsd:complexType>
  </xsd:element>
  <xsd:element name="center" />
</xsd:schema>
```

### XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<object xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
        xmlns="http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://tempuri.org/XMLSchema.xsd recur.xsd">
  <recursive>
    <recursive nm_service="vl_1" >
      <recursive>
        <center>
          <recursive>
          </recursive>
        </center>
      </recursive>
    </recursive>
  </recursive>
</object>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing namespace prefixes, for example

```
<xsd:element ref="recursive" minOccurs="0" />
```

should be

```
<xsd:element ref="p:recursive" minOccurs="0" />
```

Comment: Given the error message, this is a reasonable answer, but the XSD does have a default namespace declared.  It seems to me that OP's XSD mistakes, XML, and error message are not mutually consistent.